# array_multisort not working properly?

Tags: php, array-multisort

I'm using `array_multisort` like always, but this time it does have trouble sorting correctly.

I use it to sort a multidimensional array ($data), but I simplified the problem in this example:

```
    $data = array(6 => 'WEEK 48', 7 => 'WEEK 49', 8 => 'WEEK 47', 9 => 'WEEK 50', 10 => 'WEEK 51');

    $sort = array(8 => 201647, 6 => 201648, 7 => 201649, 9 => 201650, 10 => 201651);

    array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $data);

    Output:
    Array
    (
        [0] => WEEK 48
        [1] => WEEK 49
        [2] => WEEK 47
        [3] => WEEK 50
        [4] => WEEK 51
    )
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems your input parameters are icorrect http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_array_multisort.asp

You are sorting $sort array instead of $data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, there was a `ksort($data)` in between lines which screwed up the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?php

       $data = array(6 => 'WEEK 48', 7 => 'WEEK 49', 8 => 'WEEK 47', 9 => 'WEEK 50', 10 => 'WEEK 51');

        $sort = array(8 => 201647, 6 => 201648, 7 => 201649, 9 => 201650, 10 => 201651);

        array_multisort($data, SORT_ASC, $sort);

         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($data);

   ?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WEEK 47
    [1] => WEEK 48
    [2] => WEEK 49
    [3] => WEEK 50
    [4] => WEEK 51
)
```

Comment: I need $sort to be the sorting array, because $data is in fact a multidimensional array. Why doesn't it work the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

```
array_multisort(array1,sorting order,sorting type,array2,array3...)
```

You should provide `sorting_type` for your array

```
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $data, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC);

var_dump($sort);
var_dump($data);
```

Results:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> int(201647) 
    [1]=> int(201648) 
    [2]=> int(201649) 
    [3]=> int(201650) 
    [4]=> int(201651) 
} 

array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(7) "WEEK 47" 
    [1]=> string(7) "WEEK 48" 
    [2]=> string(7) "WEEK 49" 
    [3]=> string(7) "WEEK 50" 
    [4]=> string(7) "WEEK 51" 
}
```

Comment: $data is still not sorted properly.

Comment: i've updated answers =_= i forgot `sorting_type` for `$data`

Comment: opps, missing `sorting_order` not `sorting_type`, Sorry

Comment: But I don't want to use $data to sort, I want $data to be sorted. $data is in fact a multidimensional array.